# How to create table using 3 .csv files from a location in Impala

Tags: impala

I have three files in  a location `'/user/hive/warehouse/dig.db/'`,let files be:

`text1.csv`

`text2.csv`

`text3.csv`

How do I create table using these 3 files(which are having same headers or schema) in impala 
I have tried this but it only applies to only one file,not all three csv files. The rest 2 files data is stored under single field

```sql
create external table dig.Tunnel (
  tbm string,
  year smallint,
  month tinyint,
  day tinyint,
  hour tinyint,
  dist decimal(8,2),
  lon decimal(9,6),
  lat decimal(9,6)) 
row format delimited fields terminated by ","
location '/user/hive/warehouse/dig.db/'
```

Comment: Hi @Glinty, Could you show us a couple of lines of each file to see what is happening?

Comment: My bad, there  were two files that were not separated by ','. So if they were separated by ',', would this approach work?

Comment: Hi @Glinty, it could be a reason, but I don't really know. Another thing is `location '/user/hive/warehouse/dig.db/'` couldn't it be `location '/user/hive/warehouse/dig.db/'Tunnel/`? and then place all three files there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - to your last comment. If all your files do not have the same format, and that format doesn't match the format you have defined in the Impala table definition, then you won't see the data